# External HDD not assigned drive letter on Windows

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, filesystems

I have an external 5TB drive (Seagate Expansion Desk). It has 2 partitions (FAT32 & NTFS) with valuable files. I may have unplugged it before without doing it "safely" on Windows 10. It is now not recognised as a hard drive by Windows Explorer or diskpart.exe although seen in disk management, device manager and "devices and printers".
The option to "Change Drive letter and paths" is disabled in Disk Management, quick tests with SeatTools for Windows reveal no issues. Running out of ideas, please help.
So far I have tried:

1. updating drivers
2. uninstalling drive
3. running quick tests with SeaTools for Windows

Some screenshots:
[image: Disk Management]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to right-click the healthy 4657.21GB partition in disk management and change the drive letter? The list volume command in disk part is showing us your C: drive. You have to select disk before using list volume, you might as well remove that part of your question and the devices and printers listing. Disk management shows us all we need to see.

Comment: i have tried and it doesn't dive an option to assign letter (it's disabled). It turns out my drive is a single MacOS extended journaled partition with my Mac's time machine backups on.

Comment: @BadDisplayName: did you find a solution? I am in the exact same boat.  Trying to move data from mac to my new window 10 machine by first copying it to an external drive.  But I cannot assign it a drive letter, or see anything on the drive.  I also had formatted it as a MacOS extended journaled partition, though I did *not* use time machine to copy the data over.  Should I reformat the drive differently, then re-copy the data ? Many thanks for any advice, if you indeed found a solution.

Comment: @SherylHohman you won't be pleased to hear but i ended up formatting the drive on Windows in order to make it recognisable.

Comment: Drives **will** eventually fail.  Important files = you need at least two copies of your file, preferably three.

Answer (score 1):

Disk 1, the external HDD, has no recognized file system shown in Windows *Disk Management*.

- If you do not need the data on the disk, format at least one partition NTFS. Of course, it may no longer be Mac compatible.
- [Install Apple HFS drivers for Windows](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-hfs-windows-driver-download.1368010/) for read-only access. [Actually, I would **not recommend writing to this HDD at all** from Windows if it has essential backup data!]
- Install [Catacombae HFS Explorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/). Again, this is for read-only usage.
- Dual-boot or run Linux (e.g. [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)) from a Live CD. [You may need to install *hfsprogs* and mount the drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os):

> sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
>
> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /media/mntpoint

Though this gives write access, **do not write to the HDD if it has valued data.**